# ServiceFabric not closing CommunicationListener on update?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

We have some custom implementation ICommunicationListener and in our tests we find out that during application update the CloseAsync method of the listener is not invoked. In VS when we close app it is invoked. This is important for us because we are suspecting that it cussing our troubles during update of the application – it sometimes fails so we have to write a script that delete service and type from cluster and then installation is not failing. Rolling back on failed installation was always on node where service with ICommunicationListener existed.
Is this a know problem? How to force closing on update?

Comment: Can you try to set a **breakpoint** in services `OnAbort` method overload? Also please check that you are honoring `CancellationToken` in `RunAsync` method. When Service Fabric shutdowns the service it sets the `CancellationToken` passed to `RunAsync` method and awaits its completion before continue the shutdown process. If the `RunAsync` isn't completed in time the services `OnAbort` method is called and service replica is terminated.

Comment: We tried OnAbort but it is not executed - after testing it looks like this not cause to rollback updates (we still don’t know what is source of that and we have to unprovision whole app before update to allow app updates). This service has no RunAsync because it is WebAPI service so it is only for incoming calls. On our testing wee see that during updates service is silently shutdown (we know that because we log messages with app version to file). Close or Abort is not invoked and service is starting logging with from new version.